# IBM Worklight 6.1 common/init 401 (Unauthorized) looping error on production server

Tags: debugging, deployment, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.1 and trying to deploy on production server.
On my development server, everything works fine, but once I deploy, and then try to preview the app on browser, I have a loop of js errors saying:

```
Request [/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/common/init] worklight.js:4558
POST http://172.16.1.2:9080/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/common/init 401 (Unauthorized) worklight.js:1081
Request [/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/common/init] worklight.js:4558
POST http://172.16.1.2:9080/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/common/init 401 (Unauthorized) worklight.js:1081
Request [/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/common/init] worklight.js:4558
POST http://172.16.1.2:9080/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/common/init 401 (Unauthorized) worklight.js:1081
```

Edit: 
When testing I have the following logs:

```
2014-05-19 08:00:44.318 MyApp[33533:a0b] DEBUG:  Request [http://172.16.1.2:9080/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/iphone/init]
2014-05-19 08:00:44.336 MyApp[33533:a0b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-05-19 08:00:44.339 MyApp[33533:a0b] DEBUG:  Request [http://172.16.1.2:9080/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/iphone/init]
2014-05-19 08:00:44.348 MyApp[33533:a0b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-05-19 08:00:44.350 MyApp[33533:a0b] DEBUG:  Request [http://172.16.1.2:9080/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/iphone/init]
2014-05-19 08:00:44.356 MyApp[33533:a0b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-05-19 08:00:44.360 MyApp[33533:a0b] DEBUG:  Request [http://172.16.1.2:9080/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/iphone/init]
```

(I deployed from my console `http://172.16.1.2:9080/MyApp/console` and I am putting now my local network IP just to test that everything is OK)

And I haven't found any information in my server log

- What are these errors for?
- and how can I debug that?
- Is it related to Network issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you receive this log line **3 times** (which sounds like a problem), however this 401 is not an error per-se on its own.

When an application sends an `init` request to the server (by either using `connectOnStartup:true` or `WL.Client.connect`, it is the expected behavior to receive a **single** 401 response.

From "[Understanding predefined Worklight authentication realms and security tests](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en)":

> When new session is initiated the very first request to Worklight
>   server will get a HTTP 401 response containing WL-Instance-Id token.
>   Worklight framework will extract this token and use it as a header on
>   all subsequent requests.

I would double check in your application that you do not use *both* `connectOnStartup` and `WL.Client.connect`; it is either-or. Also check you do not use it more than once in sequence.

Comment: I am not having it 3 times, I am having an infinite number : a loop of these errors

Comment: Then you are doing something very wrong in your application. Create a new project and application, deploy it and see how it behaves. Then check what you're doing different in your actual app.

Comment: I only use     connectOnStartup:true,   and never call 
WL.Client.connect
    . Also If I put connectOnStartup:false, I still have another loop for /getuserinfo requests with the same 401 Unauthorized message

Comment: You are asking too vague questions. Produce a sample project and provide it in your question.

Comment: I disabled connectOnStartup, and commented my WL.Client.updateUserInfo, the application appears after being deployed. But adapter invokation fails, and Once I fire WL.Client.connect(), the 401 errors loop appears again

Comment: Your scenario is not clear to me. If you are an IBM customer, you can open a PMR and provide fuller server and app information and ask for help.

Comment: I tried also with an Empty Hello World App, with connectOnStartup:true and I have the same errors loop. I think I need to check the Network and may be the installation, then open a PMR if not solved

Comment: @WiPhone, was this eventually solved by tweaking the network setup, or something else? or not solved yet...

Comment: It was solved by adjusting some cookies options in the Worklight server

Comment: @WiPhone, Thanks. As usual, if you could please write this as an answer for others to benefit from it.

Comment: I don't have details - this was solved by someone else.

Comment: @WiPhone, get your co-workers to participate in stack overflow. :)

Comment: I see this same behavior after my initial session times out in my 6.1 worklight app.  We have some custom authentication going on, so will try to get to the bottom of why it's going into this loop.