# IBM WL 6.1 iPhone client connect infinite loop

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

My company is trying out Worklight.
A trial WL server is setup inside corporate network.

Devices on the Internet must reach the WL server by going through an external firewall. The firewall accepts connections to 443. Any https traffic coming to this address is reverse proxied to the internal worklight server, let’s call this `https://wl.virtual.corp.com:9443`  .

The firewall will only proxy connections, if a specific cookie value is set. To try this scenario, we created a very simple one page hello world hybrid worklight app using the DevStudio defaults, that just displays an image.

In wlInitOptions.js `connectOnStartup` is set to `false`.

In main.js `wlCommonInit()` the cookie is set with `addGlobalHeader()`, then `WL.Client.connect()` is called.

On android all is well – the wl client connects and shows the 1st page.

On iOS neither the connect success nor the connect fail callback is ever invoked.
The iOS log shows an infinite loop requesting the `https://…iphone/init` page followed by DeviceAuth – over and over without end until the app is forced down:

```
2014-06-05 16:15:03.330 Mobilithon[177:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://mobilithon-worklight.corp.com:443/worklight/apps/services/api/Mobilithon/iphone/init]
2014-06-05 16:15:03.612 Mobilithon[177:60b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-06-05 16:15:03.629 Mobilithon[177:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '16.558838' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-06-05 16:15:03.632 Mobilithon[177:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://mobilithon-worklight.corp.com:443/worklight/apps/services/api/Mobilithon/iphone/init]
2014-06-05 16:15:03.818 Mobilithon[177:60b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-06-05 16:15:03.833 Mobilithon[177:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '14.851074' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-06-05 16:15:03.837 Mobilithon[177:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://mobilithon-worklight.corp.com:443/worklight/apps/services/api/Mobilithon/iphone/init]
2014-06-05 16:15:04.022 Mobilithon[177:60b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-06-05 16:15:04.036 Mobilithon[177:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '14.554932' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-06-05 16:15:04.042 Mobilithon[177:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://mobilithon-worklight.corp.com:443/worklight/apps/services/api/Mobilithon/iphone/init]
2014-06-05 16:15:04.236 Mobilithon[177:60b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-06-05 16:15:04.251 Mobilithon[177:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '14.396973' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-06-05 16:15:04.254 Mobilithon[177:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://mobilithon-worklight.corp.com:443/worklight/apps/services/api/Mobilithon/iphone/init]
2014-06-05 16:15:04.397 Mobilithon[177:60b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-06-05 16:15:04.412 Mobilithon[177:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '14.641846' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-06-05 16:15:04.417 Mobilithon[177:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://mobilithon-worklight.corp.com:443/worklight/apps/services/api/Mobilithon/iphone/init]
2014-06-05 16:15:04.632 Mobilithon[177:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['WLApp'] took '12.687988' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-06-05 16:15:04.644 Mobilithon[177:60b] DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
2014-06-05 16:15:04.659 Mobilithon[177:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '14.371826' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2014-06-05 16:15:04.662 Mobilithon[177:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://mobilithon-worklight.corp.com:443/worklight/apps/services/api/Mobilithon/iphone/init
```

Here are the changes made to the default hybrid app files:
in initOptions.js:

```
var wlInitOptions = {
    …
     connectOnStartup : false,
     …
}
```

in index.html:

```
      <!--application UI goes here-->
       <img border="0" src="images/mcoe.png">
```

in main.js:

```
    var busyIndicator;
   function wlCommonInit() {       
       WL.Client.addGlobalHeader("Cookie", "AuthKey=foryoureyesonly");
       busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator('',{text : 'Connecting...'});
       busyIndicator.show();
       WL.Client.connect(
       {
           onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
           onFailure: onConnectFailure
       });
    }

    var onConnectSuccess = function()
    {
       // Go!
       busyIndicator.hide();
    };

    var onConnectFailure = function(error)
    {
       busyIndicator.hide();
       if(error==null) error = "No reason given";
       alert("Connection to server failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a wireshark trace of all the network requests and responses? This may help finding the cause of this issue.

Comment: You cannot set cookies like that in Worklight, since the cookie header is created internally, so whatever Cookie header you set will be replaced by the internal cookies. I am not sure if Worklight 6.1 has an API to add custom cookies to Worklight requests.

Comment: Daniel, well that is the method that IBM solutions arch provided me and it works great on Android.  Idan, the wireshark would be of SSL connections.  If that helps you, I can get them.

Comment: Idan, pcap traces and project archive attached to PMR 78711,999,000

Comment: Thanks. Since you've opened a PMR, this will be handled in the PMR.

Comment: OK, I'll update here if we figure out something.  Similar unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732861/ibm-worklight-6-1-common-init-401-unauthorized-looping-error-on-production-ser

Comment: IBM recommended the following as a work around:  document.cookie = "AuthKey=..."

Comment: That work around does work for both iOS and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around IBM provided was to set the cookie via document.cookie="..."